# Overload method error in c# console application

Tags: c#

I have a class that creates a Box that have different colors on the border. I get an error on my code that says "No overload for method 'SetCursorPosition' takes 3 arguments. Here is my code:

```
class TitledBox : ColoredBox
{
    private string title;
    private ConsoleColor titleColor;

    public TitledBox(Point p, int width, int height, ConsoleColor backColor, string title, ConsoleColor titleColor)
        : base(p, width, height, backColor)
    {
        if (title.Length > width)
            this.title = title.Substring(0, width);
        else
            this.title = title;

        this.titleColor = titleColor;
    }

    public override void Draw()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y, + j);
            Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
            if  ( j == 0)    
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = titleColor;
                Console.Write(title);
               for (int i = 0; i < width - title.Length; i++)
               {
                   Console.Write(' ');
               }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y, + j);` you might not need that second comma.

Comment: @IaroslavKovtunenko You should post it as an answer! Anytime you get the message that says "No overload for method X takes Y parameters", your first action should be to count the arguments...

Comment: @user2057693 Why you no accept any given answer below? This will mark the question as resolved, at least. Just in case: **this is what you should do if you got the answer.**

Comment: @OlleSjögren My comment has 3 up-votes, and the answers below — none. Leaving comments is better. :)

Comment: @IaroslavKovtunenko I'm guessing the upvotes on your comment and not on the answers are because you were right first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Console.SetCursorPosition should be like below

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(int Left, int Top);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Method `Console.SetCursorPosition`  gets only 2 int parameters.
You specified 3 parameters. I think you meant to say:

```
//the second comma was deleted
Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y + j);
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y, + j);
```

should be

```
    Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y + j);
```